# JNDI EnvEntry available to Spring EL in applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I'm trying to do the following:
- Configure a JNDI env-entry 'country' with value 'us'
- Get Spring to read out the env-entry 'country'
- Use it in Spring EL to load a config file

So my applicationContext would be like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:application-${country}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Problem is: how do I get the value 'java:comp/env/country' from JNDI into ${country}?

This doesn't work:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="country" jndi-name="java:comp/env/country"/>
```

****edit****

I've added `<context:property-placeholder/>` and the logs show that it finds the JNDI name, but it still refuses to use it.
Logs:

```
PropertySourcesPropertyResolver | Searching for key 'country' in [jndiProperties]
JndiTemplate         | Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/country]
JndiLocatorDelegate  | Located object with JNDI name [java:comp/env/country]
JndiPropertySource   | JNDI lookup for name [country] returned: [us]
PropertySourcesPropertyResolver | Found key 'country' in [jndiProperties] with type [String] and value 'us'
...
 Could not resolve placeholder 'country' in string value "classpath*:application-${country}.properties
```

This is really frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

I guess #{country} might work, not ${country}

Comment: Tried that but no success, looking at the logs I would say that it doesn't look at the JNDI, I can't find anything showing me that it found 'country' (if I use ${country} it shows up in the logs - see above). Ends up in a long stacktrace org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name...